# How to get the values in between two points of a stair plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to find the Y values  between two X values  using matlab from the attached plot? For example, if dx = 0.1, X = [0 5 10 12 13 14] and Y = [1 2 3 1 2.8 2], what would be the new values of Y with respect to that dx?

Please suggest.

Regards,
Imran

[image: stair plot]

Comment: This is an example. Actually I have a huge dataset with scattered data points. Would you help me to do the interpolation using sampling and holding method?

Comment: Have a look at the function called `interp1`, with option `linear`.

Comment: interp1 will not work here, and I do not want linear interpolation. Probably, I could not explain properly what I want. In the plot, for 0<=x<=5, y=1, so if I choose dx = 0.1 then for x(i) = 0: dx: 5, the value of y(i) should be 1. Again for 5<x<=10, x(i) = 5: dx:10, y(i) = 2, and so on.

Comment: I think it is on-topic, as it is about how to do this in MATLAB and not about the mathematical basics to it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to solve this with the [`interp1`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function, though of course not with the option `linear`. `interp1` has three Nearest-Neighbor options:

- `nearest` the nearest neighbor
- `next` the next higher neighbor
- `previous` the next lower neighbor

Thus, with the `previous` option, you can use `interp1` and get the desired behavior. For comparison I added a plot of the interpolation and of the stairs plot. You'll see that the interpolated version doesn't have an infinite slope, as the step happens over `dx=0.1`.

```
X = [0 5 10 12 13 14];
Y = [1 2 3 1 2.8 2];
dx = 0.1;

xi = min(X):dx:max(X);
yi = interp1(X,Y,xi,'previous');

[xs,ys] = stairs(X,Y);
plot(xi,yi,'-b',xs,ys,'-r');
```

[image: Stairs plot]

(red: original stairs plot, blue: interpolated version)

Comment: Thanks @hbaderts. But I could not get the exact figure that you attached here. And the good thing is: I've found another solution.

Comment: Executing the exact code i posted will give you this figure. My solution has the advantage that it is vectorized and will probably be faster.

Comment: @imransydney Plus hbadrters and your solutions is practically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this following solution effective.

```
x = [0 5 10  12 13 14];
y = [1 2 3 1 2.8 2];

dx = 0.1;
last_index = 1; 

xi = [ min(x) : dx : max(x) ];

for j = 1:1:length(xi)
    while  (x(last_index) < max(x)) && ( xi(j) >= x(last_index + 1))
       last_index = last_index +1 ;
    end
   yi(j) = y(last_index);
end

[Xs, Ys] = stairs(xi, yi, 'ko-');

plot(Xs, Ys, 'r-')
hold on
plot(xi, yi, 'k-')
```

[image]